# Python code for setting a number to true or false depending on the polarity

Tags: python, list, tuples, sublist

I have a list

```
import sys
A=[[51,52,-53],[51,-52,53],[199,-200,203],[-200]]
```

I need to first check if there is a sublist with only one number,
If that is true (which is true in the above case) i need to check its polarity
If its positive, then I have to set that number to true for all the same numbers in the list which are positive and false for those which are negative

My code:

```
for i in A:
    if (len(i)==1):
        single=i[0]
        for j in i:
            if (j ==single):
                if (j>0):
                    j=True
                else:
                    j=False

print A
```

Output:

```
[[51, 52, -53], [51, -52, 53], [199, -200, 203], [-200]]
```

output should have been

```
[[51, 52, -53], [51, -52, 53], [199, false, 203], [false]]
```

Comment: Please fix the question formatting.

Comment: What if there is more than one sublists with only one number?

Comment: @thefourtheye thats a good question. But yes, if there are more than one sublists with only one number di the same thing i.e True if the number is pos or else negative.

Comment: Which sublist should be considered? Lets say the one element sublists are [[1], [-1]]

Comment: @thefourtheye Ok. But my sublists are such that they will never have values 0,1,-1. also if there is a sublist say [100][-100] then 100 will become true and -100 false

Comment: Okay instead of 1 and -1, you have 200 and -200. Which one should be considered now?

Comment: Set 200 to True and -200 to false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def polarity (cnf):
sub_list = ((i[0], True) if i[0]>-1 else (i[0], False) for i in cnf if len(i) == 1)
for each in sub_list:
    for each_list in cnf:
        for ind, ele in enumerate(each_list):
            if ele == each[0]:
                each_list[ind] = each[1]
            elif ele == -each[0]:
                each_list[ind] = not each[1]
return cnf
A=[[51,52,-53],[51,-52,53],[199,-200,203],[200,203,200],[-200]]
print(polarity(A))
B=[[51,52,-53],[51,-52,53],[199,-200,203],[-52, 200],[-200],[52]]
print(polarity(B))
```

@TanveerAlam Thanks a lot for your help. I just had to add 2 more lines to get to the solution.

**Results:**
`[[51, 52, -53], [51, -52, 53], [199, False, 203], [True, 203, True], [False]]

[[51, True, -53], [51, False, 53], [199, False, 203], [False, True], [False], [True]]`

Answer (score 1):

There might be more efficient way to acheive this.

```
def polarity (my_list):
    sub_list = ((i[0], True) if i[0]>-1 else (i[0], False) for i in my_list if len(i) == 1)

    for each in sub_list:
        for each_list in my_list:
            for ind, ele in enumerate(each_list):
                if ele == each[0]:
                    each_list[ind] = each[1]

    return my_list

A=[[51,52,-53],[51,-52,53],[199,-200,203],[-200]]
print(polarity(A))
B=[[51,52,-53],[51,-52,53],[199,-200,203],[-200],[52]]
print(polarity(B))
```

**Results**:

```
[[51, 52, -53], [51, -52, 53], [199, False, 203], [False]]
[[51, True, -53], [51, -52, 53], [199, False, 203], [False], [True]]
```

Comment: There is another `-200` in the list.

Comment: @TanveerAlam: Your code works for your examples. But if have a list: 
A=[[2,3-4],[5,6,4],[4]]

It wont return [[2,3,False],[5,6,True],[True]]

Instead it gives

[[2,3,-4],[5,6,True],[True]]

Comment: @user2585254 for `A=[[2,3-4],[5,6,4],[4]]` as input  `[[2,3,-4],[5,6,True],[True]]` would be the correct output as in your question you have mentioned that you only want to check the polarity  with sublist having only one number. In our case we have `[4]` as only a sublist with single number. `[2,3-4]` is not a single element subulist. That is why it is not considering `-4` here. If input was `A=[[2,3],[-4],[5,6,4],[4]]` then you would have got `[[2, 3], [False], [5, 6, True], [True]]` as result.

Comment: @TanveerAlam Ok. that is true. I guess I did not explain my question correctly. I could explain it correctly now:
Step 1: Check for a single variable sublist
Step 2: If single variable found, look for all variables in different sublist with same number with both polarities
For eg. if the single variable found is -100, look for all sublists that contain 100's and -100's as well
Step 3: If the variable is positive make it true, else false. 
Can this be done? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user2585254 Well it seems you have found the solution.